# .CSV File Uploading Failed in c#

Tags: c#, csv

```
Upload_Excel.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("../Files/") + Assessment.QstnMasterID.ToString() + extension);
FilePath = Server.MapPath("../Files/") + Assessment.QstnMasterID.ToString() + extension;

bool Process = GameLib.GameUser.PassPath(GameUser.UserID, folderPth);
 String Error;
bool Updat=ExportCSVToDB(FilePath, extension, out Error)
 public static bool ExportCSVToDB(String FilePath, String FileExt, out string error)
        {
            try
            {
                DataTable tblReadCSV = new DataTable();

                tblReadCSV.Columns.Add("SlNo");
                tblReadCSV.Columns.Add("Question");
                tblReadCSV.Columns.Add("Topic");
                tblReadCSV.Columns.Add("Option1");
                tblReadCSV.Columns.Add("Option2");
                tblReadCSV.Columns.Add("Option3");
                tblReadCSV.Columns.Add("Option4");

                tblReadCSV.Columns.Add("Mark");
                tblReadCSV.Columns.Add("IsNegMark");
                tblReadCSV.Columns.Add("NegMark");
                tblReadCSV.Columns.Add("Objective");
                tblReadCSV.Columns.Add("Grade");
                tblReadCSV.Columns.Add("Subject");

                TextFieldParser csvParser = new TextFieldParser(FilePath);

                csvParser.Delimiters = new string[] { "," };
                csvParser.TrimWhiteSpace = true;
                csvParser.ReadLine();

                int count = 0;

                while (!(csvParser.EndOfData == true))
                {
                    tblReadCSV.Rows.Add(csvParser.ReadFields());
                    count = count + 1;
                }

              //update into database
}
 catch
 {
 }
}
```

Its my code for updating .csv file data to database.but i am getting error as File Uploading Failed (Could not find file 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\Maths-Grade 3-5.csv'.).Can anyone help me to solve.

Comment: Use a valid path, that will solve the error.

Comment: Just a wild guess, but perhaps the file `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\Maths-Grade 3-5.csv` doesn't exist? And even if it did, that's a REALLY bad place to write files other than at install time.

Comment: you need to show the code where you get the filename

Comment: i have updated a code.this code work fine in local host but it is not working in web host....i found SaveAs will not ftp data into required folder on client side.so any one heil me to resolve.

Comment: You need to have a folder in the server where the process running your website, has permissions to read and write.

Comment: i have folder,and i gaven full permission i.e,read,write and execute for public.using fillezill

Answer (score 0):

You need to grant rights to the folder for the [IIS application pool ident](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities)ity under which your application is running.